# Python-Arrange the dataframe based on a list but keep the current index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe and a sequence. I would like to arrange the dataframe based on a sequence without changing the current index of dataframe

Below is my effort but it completely changes the index. How can I fix this code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
data =pd.DataFrame({
    'Flight':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'Country':['Laos','US','UK','Aus','Sing','Malay'],
})
sequenceList=np.random.permutation(data['Flight'].values.tolist())
data.loc[sequenceList]
```

Comment: Your example shouldn't even work as you use Flight values to slice and you don't have `6` as index

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to shuffle the rows but maintain the index. Use [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) with `frac=1` and `ignore_index=True`:

```
out = data.sample(frac=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Alternatively, a fix of your method would be:

```
out = data.loc[np.random.permutation(data.index)].set_axis(data.index)
```

Output:

```
   Flight Country
0       4     Aus
1       2      US
2       5    Sing
3       6   Malay
4       3      UK
5       1    Laos
```